# Converstion from SOP to POS using boolean algebra

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

The question is this:

```
wx'y'+wyz'+w'x'z
```

I tried this technique but got stuck:

```
w(x'y'+yz')+w'x'z
(w+x'z)(w'+x'y'+yz')
(w+x')(w+z)(w'+x'y'+yz')
```

but this is not correct since it should end with 4 pos terms.

How can I convert this from sum of products to product of sums correctly?

Answer (score 0):

From this SOP (Sum Of Products) expression, wx'y' + wyz' + w'x'z, get this K-MAP (Karnaugh MAP):

```
 \ yz
  \    00  01  11  10
wx \

00     0   0   1   1

01     0   0   0   0

11     0   0   0   1

10     1   1   0   1
```

From that K-MAP, get this POS (Product Of Sums) expression:  (w+y)(w+x')(x'+y)(w'+y'+z').  Alternatively, you could use boolean algebra, but I think K-MAPs are usually easier and/or less error prone.